# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'function'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I recently upgraded from Keras 2 to Keras 3, and I am having an issue with the keras.backend.function function, that used to work fine in Keras 2, but there seems to be no replacement for it in Keras 3, and I can't find anything in the documentation.

So I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow
import keras
from keras import layers



epoch_step = 0
num_classes = 10
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)

x_100 = np.concatenate([x_train[(y_train == 1)[:]][:50], x_train[(y_train == 9)[:]][:50]])    

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)



model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),  
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),  
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),  
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'),
    ]
)


class outs1(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):          
               
        from keras import backend as K

        if batch % 20 == 0:

            inp = model.input
            outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
            functors = [K.function([inp], [out]) for out in outputs]




callbacks_list = [outs1()]


batch_size = 64
epochs = 30

model(keras.Input(shape=input_shape))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

that throws this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 18
     14 opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000003) #lr 0.000005 -> ~3min | lr 0.000001 -> >20min | lr lr_schedule: (0.000005; 10000; 0.9) -> ~10min | lr lr_schedule: (0.000005; 10000; 0.95) -> ~8min
     16 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 18 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/PhD_1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

Cell In[9], line 27
     25 inp = model.input
     26 outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
---> 27 functors = [K.function([inp], [out]) for out in outputs]


Cell In[9], line 27
     25 inp = model.input
     26 outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
---> 27 functors = [K.function([inp], [out]) for out in outputs]


AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'function'
```

Was this function gotten rid of with no replacement? Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that major changes occurred between keras `2.15.0` and `3.0.0` related to keras backend components ([Release notes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/v3.0.0)). You can also check the `keras.backend.function` definition in `2.15.0` [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/601488fd4c1468ae7872e132e0f1c9843df54182/keras/backend.py#L4625) and change for >=3.0.0 versions, from which the file does not exist anymore.

One alternative is to use `self.model.predict(data)` for which `data` needs to be available. But, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60076252/10530728), using your own custom training pipeline could be more efficient as you could be predicting more than one time for the same batch.

Nevertheless, if you can consider a fixed batch data to check the output layers, for example, you can pass this batch to the callback creation. With that, you could change the `Sequential` model to the `keras.Model` using the [functional API](https://keras.io/api/models/model/) to return the output of the layers you want as in:

`model = keras.Model(input=[inputs], output=[intermediate_layer1, intermediate_layer2, output])`

Example of the callback using `self.model.predict(data)` with a fixed batch data:

```
class outs1(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, fixed_batch_data):
        super().__init__()
        self.fixed_batch_data = fixed_batch_data

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):          

        if batch % 20 == 0:                       
            pred_outputs = self.model.predict(fixed_batch_data)
            # ... manipulate the outputs to report the layers you want


dummy_batch = some_batch_from_x_train
callbacks_list = [outs1(fixed_batch_data=dummy_batch)]
```

Comment: Again, thank you for this. I'll look into a custom training pipeline.

For now, I am getting this error when trying to run the new callback:

`NotImplementedError: Exception encountered when calling ConditionalGAN.call().

Model ConditionalGAN does not have a 'call()' method implemented.`

Do you know what might be causing that? Given that I've not had an issue with callbacks until now.