# ValueError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback, generative-adversarial-network

I have this code, which is exactly the conditional GAN from the Keras documentation (https://keras.io/examples/generative/conditional_gan/), with an added callback:

```
import keras

from keras import layers
from keras import ops
from tensorflow_docs.vis import embed
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import imageio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

batch_size = 64
num_channels = 1
num_classes = 10
image_size = 28
latent_dim = 128


# We'll use all the available examples from both the training and test
# sets.
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_100 = np.concatenate([x_train[(y_train == 1)[:]][:50], x_train[(y_train == 9)[:]][:50]])


all_digits = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test])
all_labels = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])

# Scale the pixel values to [0, 1] range, add a channel dimension to
# the images, and one-hot encode the labels.
all_digits = all_digits.astype("float32") / 255.0
all_digits = np.reshape(all_digits, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
all_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(all_labels, 10)

# Create tf.data.Dataset.
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_digits, all_labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

print(f"Shape of training images: {all_digits.shape}")
print(f"Shape of training labels: {all_labels.shape}")


generator_in_channels = latent_dim + num_classes
discriminator_in_channels = num_channels + num_classes
print(generator_in_channels, discriminator_in_channels)


# Create the discriminator.
discriminator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer((28, 28, discriminator_in_channels)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2),
        layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Dense(1),
    ],
    name="discriminator",
)

# Create the generator.
generator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer((generator_in_channels,)),
        # We want to generate 128 + num_classes coefficients to reshape into a
        # 7x7x(128 + num_classes) map.
        layers.Dense(7 * 7 * generator_in_channels),
        layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2),
        layers.Reshape((7, 7, generator_in_channels)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(1, (7, 7), padding="same", activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="generator",
)



class ConditionalGAN(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.discriminator = discriminator
        self.generator = generator
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.seed_generator = keras.random.SeedGenerator(1337)
        self.gen_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="generator_loss")
        self.disc_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="discriminator_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.gen_loss_tracker, self.disc_loss_tracker]

    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super().compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn

    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data.
        real_images, one_hot_labels = data

        # Add dummy dimensions to the labels so that they can be concatenated with
        # the images. This is for the discriminator.
        image_one_hot_labels = one_hot_labels[:, :, None, None]
        image_one_hot_labels = ops.repeat(
            image_one_hot_labels, repeats=[image_size * image_size]
        )
        image_one_hot_labels = ops.reshape(
            image_one_hot_labels, (-1, image_size, image_size, num_classes)
        )

        # Sample random points in the latent space and concatenate the labels.
        # This is for the generator.
        batch_size = ops.shape(real_images)[0]
        random_latent_vectors = keras.random.normal(
            shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim), seed=self.seed_generator
        )
        random_vector_labels = ops.concatenate(
            [random_latent_vectors, one_hot_labels], axis=1
        )

        # Decode the noise (guided by labels) to fake images.
        generated_images = self.generator(random_vector_labels)

        # Combine them with real images. Note that we are concatenating the labels
        # with these images here.
        fake_image_and_labels = ops.concatenate(
            [generated_images, image_one_hot_labels], -1
        )
        real_image_and_labels = ops.concatenate([real_images, image_one_hot_labels], -1)
        combined_images = ops.concatenate(
            [fake_image_and_labels, real_image_and_labels], axis=0
        )

        # Assemble labels discriminating real from fake images.
        labels = ops.concatenate(
            [ops.ones((batch_size, 1)), ops.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0
        )

        # Train the discriminator.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(combined_images)
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        )

        # Sample random points in the latent space.
        random_latent_vectors = keras.random.normal(
            shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim), seed=self.seed_generator
        )
        random_vector_labels = ops.concatenate(
            [random_latent_vectors, one_hot_labels], axis=1
        )

        # Assemble labels that say "all real images".
        misleading_labels = ops.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        # Train the generator (note that we should *not* update the weights
        # of the discriminator)!
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            fake_images = self.generator(random_vector_labels)
            fake_image_and_labels = ops.concatenate(
                [fake_images, image_one_hot_labels], -1
            )
            predictions = self.discriminator(fake_image_and_labels)
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))

        # Monitor loss.
        self.gen_loss_tracker.update_state(g_loss)
        self.disc_loss_tracker.update_state(d_loss)
        return {
            "g_loss": self.gen_loss_tracker.result(),
            "d_loss": self.disc_loss_tracker.result(),
        }



class outs1(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):          
               
        from keras import backend as K
        from IPython.display import clear_output

        if batch % 20 == 0:
            clear_output(wait=True)

            fig, axes = plt.subplots(12,4)


            inp = discriminator.input
            outputs = [layer.output for layer in discriminator.layers]
            functors = [K.function([inp], [out]) for out in outputs]           
            
            for i in range(12):
                layer_outs_1 = [func([x_test[i][np.newaxis,...]]) for func in functors]

                axes[i,0].imshow(x_test[i], cmap='viridis')
                axes[i,1].imshow(layer_outs_1[1][0][0,:,:,0], cmap='viridis')
                axes[i,2].imshow(layer_outs_1[3][0][0,:,:,0], cmap='viridis')
                axes[i,3].imshow(layer_outs_1[-1][0][:,:], cmap='viridis')

            
            for i in range(12):
                for j in range(5):
                    axes[i,j].axis('off')
                    axes[i,j].set_xticks([])
                    axes[i,j].set_yticks([])

            fig.set_figheight(15)
            fig.set_figwidth(8)

           
            plt.show()



callbacks_list = [outs1()]


cond_gan = ConditionalGAN(
    discriminator=discriminator, generator=generator, latent_dim=latent_dim
)
cond_gan.compile(
    d_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
    g_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
    loss_fn=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
)

cond_gan.fit(dataset, epochs=20, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

When running it, I get this error (but the code runs without errors without the callback):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 13
      4 cond_gan = ConditionalGAN(
      5     discriminator=discriminator, generator=generator, latent_dim=latent_dim
      6 )
      7 cond_gan.compile(
      8     d_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
      9     g_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0003),
     10     loss_fn=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
     11 )
---> 13 cond_gan.fit(dataset, epochs=20, callbacks=callbacks_list)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/PhD_1/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

Cell In[31], line 14
      9 clear_output(wait=True)
     11 fig, axes = plt.subplots(12,4)
---> 14 inp = discriminator.input
     15 outputs = [layer.output for layer in discriminator.layers]
     16 functors = [K.function([inp], [out]) for out in outputs]           

ValueError: The layer discriminator has never been called and thus has no defined input.
```

I have no idea how to fix it, given that the callback works on other scripts, and the Keras code works smoothly on its own.

Comment: Which keras version are you using it? It helps when the versions are also shared, as there are differences between them. Also, it will help if you explain the main idea of the callback too, since for me I got another error there.

Comment: The Keras documentation code is in Keras 3. But the callback was originally in Keras 2, hence the issue with keras.backend.function().

The idea of the callback is to visualise the input image, and the outputs from 3 layers of the discriminator for the first 12 elements in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the callback, it seems that the definition of the `inp` is wrong. You can check the section "Usage of self.model attribute" of https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/ to get a better overview. Nevertheless, the correct way of accessing the model inside a callback is by using `self.model`. As you are also trying to use the `discriminator` part, it will work with:

```
...
inp = self.model.discriminator.inputs
outputs = [layer.output for layer in self.model.discriminator.layers]
...
```

But, it seems that there are other issues as well, depending on the version. I was not able to run the last part because `K.function` does not exist on keras 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification on accessing the model in the callback.

For now I was trying to fix that issue, but yes, the absence of K.function in Keras 3 is also a problem, I posted about that too (https://stackoverflow.com/q/78166673/13505835). Is there an equivalent in Keras 3?

Comment: Yes, there is `model.predict(data)`. The `K.function` works as a wrapper around the built computacional graph. So, you can access the inputs and outputs with it. But, this seems to be replaced to a more flexible method, which is the `model.predict(data)`. I would recommend check this answer and also follow a custom training loop to be efficient at calculating this info rather than using it in a callback https://stackoverflow.com/a/60076252